# Extract data to array from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have following response reurned from an AJAX call to success function

```
{"0":"A",
"1":"B",
"2":"C",
"saved_as":["M","K","L"]}
```

Is there any way to have it in an array like following

```
dataObj[0]="A";
dataObj[1]="B";
dataObj[2]="C";
```

On a side not returned data can have more that first three elements . Last element will always be saved_as

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the numeric properties (which would make sense), you could do this:

```
var array = [];

for( var name in dataObj ) {
    if( !isNaN( +name ) ) {
        array[ name ] = dataObj[ name ];
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hW8Jm/

*(I assume the JSON data has already been parsed.)*

This enumerates the properties of `dataObj`, attempts a `toNumber` conversion using the unary `+` operator, and then checks to see if the result is `NaN` *(Not a Number)*.

If it's not `NaN` *(it is a Number)*, then the value of that property is added to the array using the property as the index of the array.

Comment: @Sonesh Dabhi: If you're using jQuery's AJAX methods, then if you simply give it a `json` dataType, jQuery will make sure it gets parsed. Otherwise you use `var parsedObj = JSON.parse(dataObj)` to parse it. To support older browsers, you can include [the JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: var dataObj = eval('('+data+')'); I am not sure whats difference between the two but this worked.

Comment: @Sonesh Dabhi: If you're receiving JSON data, then parse it as JSON. It is a secure way to receive and parse data since JSON will not allow executable code to be parsed and evaluated. If you use `.eval()`, any malicious code that may find its way in will be executed.